# use of 'out of'

Tags: prepositions

I want to make use of the word **sculpture**.
Here is an example:

> He can make his sculpture out of a plaster.

Grammatically, is  my example correct?
Can I use 'by' or 'from' or 'with' instead of 'out of'?

Comment: If "plaster" refers to the substance you would usually say "made out of plaster". "Made out of a plaster" often refers to an object, but may be used if there are several types of plaster available. Which is it here?

Comment: You can use several prepositions here *(**of, with, from,...**)* but probably ***using*** is the most likely term.

Comment: - just feed the string **was made * plaster** into Google Ngrams to see which prepositions are most common. Apparently I'm mistaken, and ***using*** is the *least* common of the top 7 hits).

Comment: @Peter yes it is a substance. Me should use 'made out of plaster'??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grammatically *He can make his sculpture out of plaster*, or *from plaster* are correct and have the same meaning. Using *by plaster* would be wrong, as you would use *by* for a process, eg *He can make his sculpture by carving a piece of plaster*. *With plaster* or *using plaster* don't actually specify that the sculpture will be made out of plaster, eg *He can make his sculpture with a hammer and chisel*.